# Function composition and forall'ed types

Tags: haskell, rank-n-types

Let's say we have some code like this, which typechecks just fine:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Foo a

type A a = forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m ()
type PA a = forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m ()
type PPFA a = forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m ()

_pfa :: PPFA a -> PA a
_pfa = _pfa

_pa :: PA a -> A a
_pa = _pa

_pp :: PPFA a -> A a
_pp x = _pa $ _pfa x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "yay"
```

We note that `_pp x = _pa $ _pfa x` is too verbose, and we try to replace it with `_pp = _pa . _pfa`. Suddenly the code doesn't typecheck anymore, failing with error messages similar to

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Foo a0 -> m0 ()’ with ‘PA a’
  Expected type: (Foo a0 -> m0 ()) -> Foo a -> m ()
    Actual type: PA a -> A a
```

I guess this is due to `m` in the definition of type aliases being `forall`'d — indeed, replacing `m` with some exact type fixes the issue. But the question is: why does `forall` break things in this case?

Bonus points for trying to figure out why replacing dummy recursive definitions of `_pfa` and `_pa` with usual `_pfa = undefined` results in GHC complaining about unification variables and impredicative polymorphism:

```
• Cannot instantiate unification variable ‘a0’
  with a type involving foralls: PPFA a -> Foo a -> m ()
    GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
• In the expression: undefined
  In an equation for ‘_pfa’: _pfa = undefined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to be clear, when you write:

```
_pa :: PA a -> A a
```

The compiler expands the type synonyms and then moves the quantifiers and constraints upward, like so:

```
_pa
  :: forall a.
     (forall m1. Monad m1 => Foo a -> m1 ())
  -> (forall m2. Monad m2 => Foo a -> m2 ())

_pa
  :: forall m2 a. (Monad m2)
  => (forall m1. Monad m1 => Foo a -> m1 ())
  -> Foo a -> m2 ()
```

So `_pa` has a rank-2 polymorphic type, because it has a forall nested to the left of a function arrow. Same goes for `_pfa`. They expect polymorphic functions as arguments.

To answer the actual question, I’ll first show you something strange. These both typecheck:

```
_pp :: PPFA a -> A a
_pp x = _pa $ _pfa x

_pp :: PPFA a -> A a
_pp x = _pa (_pfa x)
```

This, however, does not:

```
apply :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
apply f x = f x

_pp :: PPFA a -> A a
_pp x = apply _pa (_pfa x)
```

Unintuitive, right? This is because the application operator `($)` is special-cased in the compiler to allow instantiating its type variables with polymorphic types, in order to support `runST $ do { … }` rather than `runST (do { … })`.

Composition `(.)`, however, is not special-cased. So when you call `(.)` on `_pa` and `_pfa`, it instantiates their types first. Thus you end up trying to pass the *non-polymorphic* result of `_pfa`, of the type `(Foo a0 -> m0 ()) -> Foo a -> m ()` mentioned in your error message, to the function `_pa`, but it expects a polymorphic argument of type `P a`, so you get a unification error.

`undefined :: a` doesn’t typecheck because it tries to instantiate `a` with a polymorphic type, an instance of impredicative polymorphism. That’s a hint as to what you should do—the standard way of hiding impredicativity is with a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype A a = A { unA :: forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m () }
newtype PA a = PA { unPA :: forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m () }
newtype PPFA a = PPFA { unPPFA :: forall m. Monad m => Foo a -> m () }
```

Now this definition compiles without error:

```
_pp :: PPFA a -> A a
_pp = _pa . _pfa
```

With the cost that you need to explicitly wrap and unwrap to tell GHC when to abstract and instantiate:

```
_pa :: PA a -> A a
_pa x = A (unPA x)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Instantiating polymorphic type variables with polymorphic types is called impredicative polymorphism. -- [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#impredicative-polymorphism)

As the error message indicates, GHC only allows a type variable to be instantiated with a monomorphic, rank 0 type. My guess is that type checking with impredicative polymorphism is trickier to implement than it may seem.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, `Maybe a` is a polymorphic type as well, so, taking the documentation example, `id (undefined :: Maybe a)` should be rejected as it calls for impredicative polymorphism, yet it's accepted (and we quite expect it to be accepted). Does the documentation miss some explanation on a subclass of polymorphic types that cause this, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, after some further experiments `id (undefined :: (forall a. Maybe a) -> Int)` gets rejected, while enabling `ImpredicativeTypes` makes the typechecker accept it. So I assume only Rank-N types for N > 1 cause impredicative polymorphism. Is that reasonable?

Comment: @0xd34df00d It's tricky, but in `id (undefined :: Maybe a)` the polymorphic type is first instantiated with a fresh type variable and then passed to `id`, so that impredicative polymorphism is not required. Or at least I'd guess so -- check the Core if you want to be sure.