# Why can't GHC typecheck this function involving polymorphism and existential types?

Tags: haskell, types

I have some Haskell code that won't compile (with GHC 8.0.2). I think I understand the basic problem, but I would like to understand it better so I can avoid this in the future.

My library looks similar to this:

```
{-# language TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# language GADTs #-}
{-# language RankNTypes #-}

module Lib where

type Key = Int

class Handle m where
    type Connection m = c | c -> m
    withConnection :: Connection m -> m a -> IO a

class (Handle m) => Data m where
    getKeyVal :: Key -> m String

data SomeConn where
    SomeConn :: (Data m) => Connection m -> SomeConn

useConnection :: SomeConn -> (forall m. Data m => m String) -> IO String
useConnection (SomeConn c) action = withConnection c action
```

The idea is that `Data m` represents a class of monads similar to `ReaderT (Connection m) IO`. I am hoping to write generic functions with the methods of this typeclass, and have the exact method instance be determined by the connection type wrapped with `SomeConn` (which is chosen at run-time).

Now the following code

```
getKeyValWith :: SomeConn -> Key -> IO String
getKeyValWith c = (useConnection c). getKeyVal
```

gives me the following error from GHC 8.0.2:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘m0 String’
                 with ‘forall (m :: * -> *). Data m => m String’
  Expected type: m0 String -> IO String
    Actual type: (forall (m :: * -> *). Data m => m String)
                 -> IO String
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘useConnection c’
  In the expression: useConnection c . getKeyVal
  In an equation for ‘getKeyValWith’:
      getKeyValWith c = useConnection c . getKeyVal
```

Strangely enough, the following works just fine:

```
getKeyValWith c k = useConnection c (getKeyVal k)
```

Less surprisingly, so does this:

```
getKeyValWith (SomeConn c) = withConnection c . getKeyVal
```

Is there a simple rule to understand why GHC doesn't like the first example, but the other examples are okay? Is there a way I can ask GHC for more information about what it's doing when it tries to compile the first definition? I understand this is probably not idiomatic Haskell (what some call the "Existential/typeclass anti-pattern").

**Edit:**

I should add that I run into the same problem even if I explicitly add the type `getKeyVal :: Key -> (Data m => m String)` in the first example. I can even give this function its own name with my chosen type signature (which typechecks), but I get the same error. But I see now that even when I explicitly add the type, running `:t` in GHCI (with `-XRankNTypes`) on it gives me back the original type with `Data m =>` floated to the left. So I think I understand why GHC is balking at me. Can I force GHC to use my chosen type?

Comment: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition/9469942#9469942) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343239/type-error-with-rank-2-types-and-function-composition/8343964#8343964) but the content seems obscured by the discussion of `($)`. I am trying to understand what the problem is in general, and how I can either help GHC understand my code, or ask GHC to help me understand the problem.

Comment: The type of `(. getKeyVal)` is `Data m => (m String -> c) -> Key -> c`; the type of `useConnection c` is `(forall m. Data m => m String) -> IO String`. Do you see why the types `m String -> IO String` and `(forall m . Data m => m String) -> IO String` cannot unify? Neither of the latter two definitions require performing this unification.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943793/function-composition-and-foralled-types

Comment: This might be a near-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964162/could-not-match-polymorphic-type-in-haskell

Comment: @user2407038, I do see that, and I edited my question to ask a new one: Can I force GHC to accept a different type signature on `getKeyVal`?

Comment: @chi, the answer there mentions instantiating `(.)` as an issue. But in my edit, I think I'm running into an issue even before `(.)` comes into play.

Comment: @dunnl Aren't you still using `(.)` in your edit? That can't work since its type variables can not be instantiated to the polymorphic type, I think.

Comment: @chi My concern was that in GHCI, `:t getKeyVal :: Key -> (Data m => m String)` returns `getKeyVal :: Data m => Key -> m String`, without yet talking about `(.)`. My belief now is that the type is somewhat flexible (w.r.t. the exact location of the `forall`), and indeed the issue is `(.)` as you say.

Comment: Ah, yes. `forall a . ...` and `Context => ...` are automatically hoisted -- moved to the top level if possible. This is usually not an issue, though. I.e. if I write `f :: Int -> forall a . a` it gets changed to `f :: forall a. Int -> a`, but after I apply `f 5` I get again `forall a. a`, so everything is mostly OK. Even composition usually works fine with that hoisting. A major problem, instead, is if composition requires to involve a polymorphic type, requiring impredicativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all about `.`. It's unable to pass a polymorphic argument between the functions, hence `f . g` doesn't work if `f` is rank-2 polymorphic. Notice the following works:

```
(~.) :: ((∀ m. Data m => m String) -> z) -> (x -> (∀ m. Data m => m String))
          -> x -> z
(~.) f g x = f (g x)

getKeyValWith :: SomeConn -> Key -> IO String
getKeyValWith c = useConnection c ~. getKeyVal
```

Ideally, `.` would have a type like

```
(.) :: ∀ c . ((∀ y . c y => y) -> z) -> x -> ((∀ y . c y => y) -> x)
               -> x -> z
```

and thus cover all special cases like `~.` above. But this is not possible – it would require inferring the weakest possible constraint `c` to pick in any given situation – in the traditional case, `c y = y~y₀` – and I'm pretty sure that is uncomputable in general.

(An interesting question is how far we could get if the compiler just inlined `.` as much as possible *before type-checking*, as it right now already does with `$`. If it did automatic eta-expansion, it could certainly get `useConnection c . getKeyVal` to work, but automatic eta-expansion is in general not a good idea...)

Hiding the Rank-2 polymorphism by wrapping the polymorphic argument in a GADT, as you did with `SomeConn`, is the usual workaround.

Comment: In light of the edit to my question, it appeared to me that GHC simply wouldn't allow me to say `getKeyVal :: Key -> (Data m => m String)` (or rather it would, but GHCI refuses to give me back a rank 2 type with `:t`). Would you say that my observation is just a red herring? It seems now that GHC is flexible with exact type of `getKeyVal` until it appears in a specific context.

Comment: You can always move a universal quantifier out of the result of a function, that's why querying GHCi for `:t _ :: Key -> (∀ m . Data m => m String)` gives `∀ m . Data m => Key->m String`. But in case the type variable doesn't appear in the arguments, this can also be inverted and GHC will in fact happily do that, so there's no problem there.